# Which protocols/connection methods are used to connect to an Azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-automation, azcopy

1. Ping uses ICMP protocol
2. RDP uses TCP protocol (how different is this from WinRM?)
3. Azure DevOps uses RDP/Winrm? (tasks such as: WindowsMachineFileCopy(uses Robocopy),
   PowerShellOnTargetMachines)
4. What does AzCopy use to move files between storage account and VM?
5. What method does Azure Automation runbook use? (Clearly it is not what
   DevOps use because I have hardened private VMs not accessible by Azure
   DevOps but can be accessed to run scripts inside the VM with ease using Automation Runbooks)
   Edit:
   Hardened  VM = registry settings forbidding the VM via firewall and winrm (disabled). So all connections coming into the VM is forbidden.   Even a selfhosted agent fails. But automation runbook succeedes to connect to the VM.

Comment: What’s the exact scenario where Automation Runbook connects to VM in this case?

What does AzCopy use to move files between storage account and VM? It uses the standard Azure Storage REST APIs( It relies on HTTP) which is based on TCP.

Comment: To copy files from git to the VM

Comment: You can use self hosted agents, which will initiate the connection from the VM, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops

Comment: No it did not. Hence the question

Answer (score 0):

What does AzCopy use to move files between storage account and VM? **It uses the standard Azure Storage REST APIs( It relies on HTTP) which is based on TCP**.

To copy files from git to the VM : You can use self hosted agents, which will initiate the connection from the VM, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops  **It uses HTTPS**

Comment: It is a hardened VM. So not accessible via selfhosted agent

Comment: Not sure what is the ask. Connection is initiated from the VM, not coming to the VM

Comment: Hardened  VM = registry settings forbidding the VM via firewall and winrm disable. So all connections coming into the VM is forbidden.   So a selfhosted agent fails. But automation runbook succeedes